# create a FTS in sql2005 on multile fields in multiple tables?

Tags: full-text-search

How can I create a Full Text Search catalog on 3 fields where one is in a second table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to create a view and create an FT index on this view

From [MSDN "Getting Started with Full-Text Search"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx) (my bold)

> Create a full-text index on the table or **indexed view**

I haven't tried this myself so don't have any tips. However, an indexed view is the only way to have any index span tables.

Comment: since 2 of my 3 fields are in a table can i add the third as a calculated field and have a  FTS on the single table? I am trying to make a FTS on Message.Subject, Message.Body and MessageRecipient.FriendlyName

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to create an "indexed view" that combines the two tables into a view.  You can then build the full text index on that.

Here is the documentation you need direct from Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: what about adding a calculated field to the table that would add the other table's data. sort of like a join?

Comment: To use a calculated field that needs data from another source you'd have to build it into a function.  You'd then reference the function in the calculated field.  Once you did that I'm not sure the field would be available for full text indexing.  I've frankly never tried it.  Even if it did work I think building an indexed view would be cleaner and more performant.  Above you say, "sort of like a join" - an indexed view actually is a join.  Behind the scenes sql builds a little table from the join that it can index and search.